# Java: Maven project: Distinct test automation architecture

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, structure, project, browser-automation

Hello stackoverflowers!

I have a question to test automation (Selenium) specialists with several years experience:
**What is the best/distinct test automation architecture/structure of files in Java (Maven) project?** Example structures are provided below.

UI view of a system:

3 pages: home, registration, accounts.

---

1.1.1. "Home" page has search bar with "First name" field and "Search" button.

1.1.2. "Accounts" page has the same type of search bar as "Home" page has, but with "First name", "Last name" fields and "Search" button.

---

1.2.1. "Registration" page has "button1" to open "modal window1", which has 2 radio buttons.

1.2.2. "Accounts" page has "button2" to open "modal window2", which has the same 2 radio buttons as "modal window1" has and 1 "Code" field.

---

Structures:

1.

- System

  - home

    - home Page Objects

      - "First name" field
      - "Search" button
  - registration

    - registration Page Objects

      - "button1"
      - radio button 1
      - radio button 2
  - accounts

    - accounts Page Objects

      - "First name" field
      - "Search" button
      - "Last name" field
      - "button2"
      - radio button 1
      - radio button 2
      - "Code" field

2.

- System

  - Forms

    - Forms Page Objects

      - "button1"
      - "button2"
  - Search bars

    - Search bars Page Objects

      - "First name" field
      - "Last name" field
      - "Search" button
  - Modal windows

    - Modal windows Page Objects

      - radio button 1
      - radio button 2
      - "Code" field

**Which of these 2 architectures/structures is the better/more distinct one?**

Thanks in advance for a suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You can use NoraUi framework (Gherkin > Cucumber > Java (Step/page/Selenium)).

- [Maven archetype](https://github.com/NoraUi/noraui-archetype) for create a Robot.
- [Official documentation](https://noraui.github.io/#)
- You can learn [here](https://github.com/NoraUi/noraui-academy)
- Lot of sample [here](https://github.com/NoraUi/NoraUi/tree/master/src/test/resources/steps)

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I haven't heard of NoraUi. I used simply Cucumber + Java (Selenium). However, your tip does not answer my question, unfortunately - how to structure common page elements?